# How can i display array to show integer?

Tags: java, android, arrays, matrix

I want to display something like this:

```
1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
2 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
...
9 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Nothing works

```
int[][] areas = new int[9][9];
for(int j=0; j<=8; j++)
{ // do i need to initialize here first array? something like areas [j][] = j ;
  // how can i do that?
  for(int i=0; i<=8; i++)
  {
    areas[j][i] = i;
    Log.d("tiles", String.valueOf(areas[j][i])); // here i get from 1 to 9, 9 times
  }
  Log.d("area", String.valueOf(areas[j])); 
//here is the problem
//i want to show 1 {for all tiles for this 1 area}, than 2 {for all tiles for 
//this 2 area}... for each but it only display an address
}
```

I want to have control when I want to go to area 6 to tile 5 for example

Comment: I don't understand your problem but `areas[j]` is an array. So if you want print that you need to change `String.valueOf(areas[j])` to `Arrays.toString(areas[j])`

Comment: hi, thx for answering, i got array of array i know that, i want to display only the first array of array, if you know what i mean... i want to get array 1 of items, than array 2 of items , than array 3 of items... do you get it ?

Comment: how can i put at the first array 1 , than 2 , than 3...

Comment: i want to show areas [j][] thats all .. first only

Comment: first element of jth row? areas[j][0] should do it

Comment: 1* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
2* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
...
9* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} i want to display 1*,2*,...9*

Comment: but how do it in a for ?

Comment: i can display 1,2,3,4,5...9 inside numbers, but not the 1*,2*...9*

Answer (score 4):

Try [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]))

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
String s = Arrays.toString(arr).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}");
for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + s);
}
```

**Ouput**

```
1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
2 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
3 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
4 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
5 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
6 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
7 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
8 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
9 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: hi, thx for answering, i want to display first array, to show 1,2,3,4...9.. how can i do that? something like this show array of j

Comment: i need an array of array

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[][] areas = new int[10][10];
    for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + 1);
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            areas[j][i] = i;
            if (areas[j][i] < 8) {
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(areas[j][i] + 1) + ","); // here i get from 1 to 9, 9 times
            } else {
                System.out.print(String.valueOf(areas[j][i] + 1));
            }
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}2{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}3{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}4{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}5{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}6{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}7{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}8{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}9{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: Hi, This is not for android. It is for Java.